# SQLite not Deleting records with multiple conditions

Tags: sqlite

**Sorry..! It was a logical mistake.! I solved it.!**

It is not deleting anything, but there are records, what's wrong?

SQLite Code:

```
dbWritable.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_Student_ID + " == " + Student_ID + " AND " + COL_ID + " NOT IN " + pramIDs, null);
```

Query:

```
DELETE FROM student_attendances
WHERE Student_ID == 1036 AND ID NOT IN 
(733703,733745,733787,733829,733871,733913,733955,733997,734039,734081,734123,734165,734207,734249,734291,734333,734375,734417,734459,734501,734543,734585,734627,734669,734711,734753,734795,734837,734879,734921,734963,735005,735047,735089,735131,735173,735215,735257,735299,735341,735383,735425,735467,735509,735551,735593,735635,735677,735719,735761,735803,735845,735887,735929,735971,736013,736055,736097,736139,736181,736223,736265,736307,736349,736391,736433,736475,736517,736559,736601 )
```

Comment: Use a single `=`: `Student_ID = 1036`

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I did not get any error message.!

Comment: are you sure you have students who DON'T have any of those ids? if you don't get any errors, then obviously the query didn't match anything, so nothing got deleted.

Comment: @juergend I tried "=" instead of  "==" but still nothing

Comment: @MarcB I'm pretty sure.!

Comment: "pretty sure" isn't "sure". change that to a select query. if you don't get any records, then obviously there are no matching records.

Comment: Are you committing the change?  If not, the records will not be deleted.

Comment: my apologies... it was a logical mistake.. sorry for wasting your time..! thank you.!